# Hierarchical Multi-Class Classification

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I have a e-commerce category structure where each parent category can have subcategories. For example:

Parent Category 1 -> Sub Category Level 1 -> Sub Category level 2 -> Sub Category Level 3
Parent Category 2 -> Sub Category Level 1 -> Sub Category level 2

Also I have all the search keyword from a e-commerce website.

**My problem is to assign the correct sub-category Hierarchy to the search query**.

Required input and output are given below:

Input:

Search-Keyword; Category L1, Category L2, Category L3

Office Chair;Furniture;Chair & Seating;Office Chairs
Hp Laptop;Technology;Computers & Laptops;Laptop
Apple ipad;Technology;Tablet
Dark Coffee;breakroom;Coffee

If the search keyword entered by the end user on the e-commerce website are:

Desktop Monitor
Light Coffee

Then output file should contain correct classification of the search keywords as given below:

Desktop Monitor;Technology;Computers & Laptops
Light Coffee;breakroom;Coffee

I have tried multi-class classification of the parent category with the use of LSTM and word embedding using keras and able to assign

Office Chair -> Furniture

Let me know if anyone have worked on similar problem.

Comment: what is your inputs? do you have labels? It is not clear what you are predicting or training on

Comment: You described a problem broadly, what is your question?

Comment: Yes, I have all the pre-defined label for training data, some of the input added in description

Comment: @NathanMcCoy Added some more details, please check

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, Normally we do classification based on given label, if we have labels in form of various levels and we have to select labels from any levels

Comment: you need to define a taxonomy of types, then a system that will predict the categorical type.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy thanks for the answer. What do you mean by taxonomy of types

Comment: define a hierarchy of these categories and a model which can predict the nodes in the hierarchy, then one prediction entails its parents. read about taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

I suggest train a classifier for children of each node in your hierarchy tree. for example classifier number 1 classify items between parent category 1 and parent category 2 (2 class classification). Then train a classifier with items of parent category 1 that classify between items between subcategory1, subcategory2 and suncategory3 (3 class classification). and so on.

Comment: I have more than 15 parent category, for each node I have at-least 4 sub-node till level 4. I need to train more than 100 classifier to train. Is that what you suggesting?

Comment: Yes, of course I did not know your hierarchy is this big. Now if your hierarchy is exactly a tree (each child node just has one parent), if you considers leaf nodes in tree as your classes, and train a classifier for them and then for each one traverse from it to the root to get all category hierarchy. It is called flat classification, but there is more complicated classification methods you can find them by searching "Hierarchical Classification"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already checked so many papers. Please suggest some source if you have